# Iterative insertion of attributes in XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery

I have an a huge XML document part of which is as

```
<tracklist>
  <track>
    <position>A1</position>
    <title>Un Momento Solo (North 5th. St. Dub)</title>
    <duration>6:04</duration>
  </track>
  <track>
    <position>A2</position>
    <title>Your Love Is Incredible</title>
    <duration>6:44</duration>
  </track>
  <track>
    <position>B1</position>
    <title>Roots</title>
    <duration>7:43</duration>
  </track>
  <track>
    <position>B2</position>
    <title>Un Momento Solo (Straight Up Mix)</title>
    <duration>7:06</duration>
  </track>
</tracklist>
```

I would like to add an attribute to `tracklist` called `tot` with the total number of subnodes under `tracklist` called `track`

```
for $i in db:open("releases1","releases.xml")/releases/release
return update insert attribute tot {count($i/tracklist/track)} into 
$i/tracklist/track
```

However, I am getting an error

```
[XPST0003] Unexpected end of query: 'insert attribut...'.
```

Comment: Please do _never_ post textual input or code as images, they prevent anybody working with it. Instead provide the original file, or a (well-formed) excerpt from it matching your query (thus, including at least the relevant parts). Have a look at [ask] to see what a good question should include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a minor syntax problem. The syntax of update statements is

```
insert node [node] into [target-node]
```

where the keyword(s) `insert node` always occurs together, if I remember correctly using two words here had some grammatical reasons (otherwise, there could've been some ambiguity during parsing).

For your example, remove the `update` keyword (which does not exist) and add the missing `node`:

```
for $i in db:open("releases1","releases.xml")/releases/release
return insert node attribute tot {count($i/tracklist/track)} into 
$i/tracklist
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I posted the code as requested in the question form. The code in your rely is correct but the last `track` is not needed. It creates an error

Comment: I copied that from your question; as there was no proper example input yet (BaseX' visualization is nice for exploration when working with it, but makes understanding the structure much harder than some XML snippet) I could hardly verify the semantics of the query. The updated question brings pretty much everything a good question needs: Example input, a clear description what you're trying to achieve, what you tried and a clear problem statement, +1 for that.